# Как перенести свой статичный шаблон на CMS?

Tags: cms

Решил апгрейднуть сайт с статичного на динамичный. Требуется лишь возможность заполнения контента на одной страничке. То есть нужно пополнять раздел меню. Стал искать бесплатный *CMS* и выбор пал на *Joomla*.

Потому что бесплатный (*WordPress* на базовом аккаунте не давал возможность загружать свои шаблоны). После установки столкнулся с проблемой, что невозможно просто так перекинуть свой шаблон на движок, нужно делать каркас итд. А терять дизайн и структуру своего не хочется.

Может есть какие то решения по проще верстки нового шаблона? Или же другой движжок? Важно что бы другой движок был дружелюбен к стандартам продвижения.

Comment: "WordPress на базовом аккаунте не давал возможность загружать свои шаблоны" - ничего не понял. На каком таком аккаунте? Это свободное ПО, которое можно скачать и установить. И делать с ним все, что угодно.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Но после того как я скачал WP, я не обнаружил возможности добавить свою тему, то есть мою обычную верстку html/css. В поисках решения, наткнулся на одну статью где сказано, что нельзя добавлять свои шаблоны в бесплатной версии. Я не шарю, но вот ссылка: [https://toster.ru/q/240071] . Если это не так, то подскажите как можно добавлять свои шаблоны.

Comment: Не читайте toster )) На WP можно установить любую тему. В официальном репозитории - огромные выбор. Можно создать от неё дочернюю и вносить свои правки (в том числе свой html на отдельных страницах). Это самый правильный путь. Можно создать и свою тему, но это не для начинающих.